# Pandas to sum and group by date index

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a list of records which I need to calculate sums per reference and group by month.

Input

```
Date1;Date2;Company;Reference;Description;Value;Currency;
24.01.2014;23.01.2014;Company1;Debit;Text;-100,00;EUR;
24.01.2014;24.01.2014;Company2;Debit;Text;-130,00;EUR;
21.01.2014;24.01.2014;Company1;Debit;Text;-50,00;EUR;
21.01.2014;21.01.2014;Company3;Credit;Text;600,00;EUR;
17.02.2014;16.01.2014;Company2;Debit;Text;-110,00;EUR;
16.02.2014;16.01.2014;Company1;Credit;Text;40,00;EUR
02.03.2014;02.03.2014;Company6;Debit;Text;90,00;EUR
```

Desired Output

```
         Credit Debit
Date1                                                                  
2014-01; 600;   -180   
2014-02; 40;    -110   
2014-03; NaN;   -90
```

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
DATA = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\File.txt'
CLEAN_VALUE=DATA['Value'].str.replace('.','').str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
DATA['CLEAN_VALUE']=CLEAN_VALUE
SUM=DATA['CLEAN_VALUE'].groupby(DATA['Reference']).sum()
DATA['Date1']=pd.to_datetime(DATA['Date1'],dayfirst=True,unit='D')
summe=DATA[:10].groupby(['Date1','Reference']).sum().unstack()
Sorted=pd.date_range(2013-01-01,2014-03-01,freq="M").resample('H', how=len)
```

It is actually working fine until the last step when I try to group by month. I receive this error:

> ```
> Error message TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.
> ```

Answer (score 5):

This requires 0.13.1 (for the `infer_datetime_format`). This is much faster than
using a dateparser directly. This will convert the datelike to the proper `datetime64[ns]` dtypes.

```
In [75]: df = read_csv(StringIO(data),
               sep=';',
               decimal=',',
               infer_datetime_format=True,
               parse_dates=['Date1','Date2']
              ).dropna(how='all',axis=1)

In [76]: df
Out[76]: 
       Date1      Date2   Company Reference Description  Value Currency
0 2014-01-24 2014-01-23  Company1     Debit        Text   -100      EUR
1 2014-01-24 2014-01-24  Company2     Debit        Text   -130      EUR
2 2014-01-21 2014-01-24  Company1     Debit        Text    -50      EUR
3 2014-01-21 2014-01-21  Company3    Credit        Text    600      EUR
4 2014-02-17 2014-01-16  Company2     Debit        Text   -110      EUR
5 2014-02-16 2014-01-16  Company1    Credit        Text     40      EUR
6 2014-03-02 2014-03-02  Company6     Debit        Text     90      EUR

[7 rows x 7 columns]
```

This requires 0.14/master, and will be the new easy way to do a multiple grouping with a time based and other grouper.

```
In [77]: df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='MS',key='Date1'),'Reference']).sum().unstack()
Out[77]: 
             Value       
Reference   Credit  Debit
Date1                    
2014-01-01     600   -280
2014-02-01      40   -110
2014-03-01     NaN     90

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

< 0.14/master you can do this:

```
In [79]: df.set_index('Date1').groupby(lambda x: (x.year,x.month)).apply(lambda x: x.groupby('Reference').sum()).unstack()
Out[79]: 
            Value       
Reference  Credit  Debit
(2014, 1)     600   -280
(2014, 2)      40   -110
(2014, 3)     NaN     90

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> df = pd.read_table(StringIO('''\
... Date1;Date2;Company;Reference;Description;Value;Currency;
... 24.01.2014;23.01.2014;Company1;Debit;Text;-100,00;EUR;
... 24.01.2014;24.01.2014;Company2;Debit;Text;-130,00;EUR;
... 21.01.2014;24.01.2014;Company1;Debit;Text;-50,00;EUR;
... 21.01.2014;21.01.2014;Company3;Credit;Text;600,00;EUR;
... 17.02.2014;16.01.2014;Company2;Debit;Text;-110,00;EUR;
... 16.02.2014;16.01.2014;Company1;Credit;Text;40,00;EUR
... 02.03.2014;02.03.2014;Company6;Debit;Text;90,00;EUR'''),
... sep=';', decimal=',', parse_dates=['Date1', 'Date2'],
... date_parser=lambda t: dt.datetime.strptime(t, '%d.%m.%Y').date())
>>>
>>> df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
>>> df
        Date1       Date2   Company Reference Description  Value Currency
0  2014-01-24  2014-01-23  Company1     Debit        Text   -100      EUR
1  2014-01-24  2014-01-24  Company2     Debit        Text   -130      EUR
2  2014-01-21  2014-01-24  Company1     Debit        Text    -50      EUR
3  2014-01-21  2014-01-21  Company3    Credit        Text    600      EUR
4  2014-02-17  2014-01-16  Company2     Debit        Text   -110      EUR
5  2014-02-16  2014-01-16  Company1    Credit        Text     40      EUR
6  2014-03-02  2014-03-02  Company6     Debit        Text     90      EUR

[7 rows x 7 columns]
```

so far was just reading the data and parsing the values, the actual `groupby` step is very short:

```
>>> df['month'] = df.Date1.apply(dt.date.strftime, args=('%Y.%m',))
>>> df.groupby(['month', 'Reference'])['Value'].aggregate(sum).unstack()
Reference  Credit  Debit
month                   
2014.01       600   -280
2014.02        40   -110
2014.03       NaN     90

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```